# Repository issue with the installation of QGIS

Tags: 18.04, qgis

I got a problem when I switched from 16.04 to 18.04.
QGIS is no longer installed. So I tried to install it again.
I though my problem was from my list (/etc/apt/sources.list)

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list

deb https://qgis.org/debian bionic main
deb-src https://qgis.org/debian bionic main
```

But after many attempts I can't install QGIS due to this message :

```
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Certains paquets ne peuvent être installés. Ceci peut signifier
que vous avez demandé l'impossible, ou bien, si vous utilisez
la distribution unstable, que certains paquets n'ont pas encore
été créés ou ne sont pas sortis d'Incoming.
L'information suivante devrait vous aider à résoudre la situation : 

Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 python-qgis : Dépend: python3-pyqt5 mais il n'est pas installable
               Dépend: python3-pyqt5.qtsql mais il n'est pas installable
               Dépend: python3-pyqt5.qtsvg mais il n'est pas installable
               Dépend: python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit mais il n'est pas installable
               Dépend: python3-sip mais il n'est pas installable
               Dépend: python-qgis-common (= 1:3.4.2+28bionic) mais ne sera pas installé
               Dépend: python3-pyqt5.qsci mais il n'est pas installable
               Dépend: python3-future mais il n'est pas installable
               Dépend: python3-plotly mais il n'est pas installable
               Dépend: python3-pyproj mais il n'est pas installable
               Dépend: python3-owslib mais il n'est pas installable
               Dépend: libsqlite3-mod-spatialite mais il n'est pas installable
               Dépend: libqgispython3.4.2 mais ne sera pas installé
               Dépend: libqca-qt5-2 (>= 2.0.2) mais il n'est pas installable
               Dépend: libqgis-3d3.4.2 mais ne sera pas installé
               Dépend: libqgis-analysis3.4.2 mais ne sera pas installé
               Dépend: libqgis-core3.4.2 mais ne sera pas installé
               Dépend: libqgis-gui3.4.2 mais ne sera pas installé
               Dépend: libqgis-server3.4.2 mais ne sera pas installé
               Dépend: libqscintilla2-qt5-13 (>= 2.8.4) mais il n'est pas installable
               Recommande: liblwgeom-dev mais il n'est pas installable
 qgis : Dépend: libqgis-analysis3.4.2 mais ne sera pas installé
        Dépend: libqgis-app3.4.2 mais ne sera pas installé
        Dépend: libqgis-core3.4.2 mais ne sera pas installé
        Dépend: libqgis-gui3.4.2 mais ne sera pas installé
        Dépend: libqt5keychain1 (>= 0.7.0) mais il n'est pas installable
        Dépend: qgis-providers (= 1:3.4.2+28bionic) mais ne sera pas installé
        Dépend: qgis-common (= 1:3.4.2+28bionic) mais ne sera pas installé
 qgis-plugin-grass : Dépend: qgis-provider-grass (= 1:3.4.2+28bionic) mais ne sera pas installé
                     Dépend: libqgis-app3.4.2 mais ne sera pas installé
                     Dépend: libqgis-core3.4.2 mais ne sera pas installé
                     Dépend: libqgis-gui3.4.2 mais ne sera pas installé
                     Dépend: libqgisgrass7-3.4.2 mais ne sera pas installé
                     Dépend: grass-core mais il n'est pas installable
                     Dépend: grass740 mais il n'est pas installable
E: Impossible de corriger les problèmes, des paquets défectueux sont en mode « garder en l'état ».
```

I apologize for the language, I'm not familiar yet to how to post in a better view should I add space each line?. At least thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue from my side.

I solved removing all configured repos (e.g. UbunguGIS) and install the one in the official ubuntu repo (v. 2.18).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu, you should probably use the repository designed for Ubuntu: `https://qgis.org/ubuntu` if you want the latest stable (currently 3.4), or `https://qgis.org/ubuntu-ltr` if you want the current Long-Term Release (currently 3.4 too).

For example, you can add the following lines to your list of sources in `etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb     https://qgis.org/ubuntu-ltr bionic main
deb-src https://qgis.org/ubuntu-ltr bionic main
```

After that, you can add the key, update and install the necessary packages.

More details are listed here:

https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu